# How to tell linker which library/function to prefer when getting LNK2005?

Tags: c, visual-c++, linker, wdk

This question is about a driver and how to cherry-pick symbols from a static library *or* an import library as needed. And yes, I **need *both* libraries** in question, because they provide *non-overlapping* sets of functions (defined in one but not the other) which I need.

So I am working on migrating a driver to the formal WDK build process. And I see the following errors:

```
libcntpr.lib(_ctype.obj) : error LNK2005: isupper already defined in ntoskrnl.lib(ntoskrnl.exe)
libcntpr.lib(_ctype.obj) : error LNK2005: islower already defined in ntoskrnl.lib(ntoskrnl.exe)
libcntpr.lib(_ctype.obj) : error LNK2005: isdigit already defined in ntoskrnl.lib(ntoskrnl.exe)
libcntpr.lib(_ctype.obj) : error LNK2005: isxdigit already defined in ntoskrnl.lib(ntoskrnl.exe
libcntpr.lib(_ctype.obj) : error LNK2005: isspace already defined in ntoskrnl.lib(ntoskrnl.exe)
```

Now in all of these cases I would like the linker to prefer `ntoskrnl.lib` (an import library) instead of the static library `libcntpr.lib`.

Plenty of these functions had been reimplemented in the driver, but I'd rather use a proven implementation instead - and so I am trying to link to their implementations in `ntoskrnl.exe`.

So how can I tell the linker to prefer one library over the other, or better yet tell it per-function?

By adding `LINKER_FLAGS=/force:multiple $(LINKER_FLAGS) /wx:no`, it seems, I can force the linker to ignore the second definition (I am assuming it's taking the order in which the libraries are passed to determine the order?) and then get warnings instead:

```
libcntpr.lib(_ctype.obj) : warning LNK4006: _isupper already defined in ntoskrnl.lib(ntoskrnl.exe); second definition ignored
libcntpr.lib(_ctype.obj) : warning LNK4006: _islower already defined in ntoskrnl.lib(ntoskrnl.exe); second definition ignored
libcntpr.lib(_ctype.obj) : warning LNK4006: _isdigit already defined in ntoskrnl.lib(ntoskrnl.exe); second definition ignored
libcntpr.lib(_ctype.obj) : warning LNK4006: _isxdigit already defined in ntoskrnl.lib(ntoskrnl.exe); second definition ignored
libcntpr.lib(_ctype.obj) : warning LNK4006: _isspace already defined in ntoskrnl.lib(ntoskrnl.exe); second definition ignored
```

**Question:** Is there a better, perhaps more granular, approach that I could use to guide the linker the way I want to?

[This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/148652) seems to suggest that it's possible to provide ordering by using `/nodefaultlib:libname1;libname2`, but I haven't gotten this to work (but I only tried the short names instead of the full path as it's passed via `makefile.new` and `sources`).

---

Technically the linker is VS 2005 with some patches applied (`link.exe` version: 8.00.50727.278). But I am using the 6001.18002 WDK (Windows Driver Kit SP1 for Windows Server 2008/Vista).

Another alternative I have considered is to use `lib.exe /extract:membername` to export the object files from the `.lib` and link to those. But it seems even more cumbersome this way.

NB: I am also still pondering to replace `libcntpr.lib` by `ntstrsafe.lib`, but the linker behavior would be the same.

Comment: Implement a wrapper that import with different names those functions?

Comment: You are solving the wrong problem.  This is dangerous for other reasons, you never want to accidentally link a CRT function that you should never use in a driver.  Right now you get no error for that.  Find out how these CRT functions ended up in that library, fix that instead.

Comment: @HansPassant: you do realize that both `libcntpr.lib` _and_ `ntstrsafe.lib` are in fact _meant_ to be used in kernel mode, right? And either way I'd rather use a version of the function used and provided by Microsoft rather than one that my predecessor(s) wrote. **Both** `libcntpr.lib` and `ntstrsafe.lib` are libraries provided *by Microsoft* to be linked into certain types of drivers. And while I am aware of the risks, this is legacy code and I need to solve one problem after the other. And the first is to get this to build - preferably without warnings.